# SocketException: Address already in use MONGODB

Tags: mongodb, macos, homebrew

i found this error when trying to run mongodb. I install it via homebrew. Please assist

```
Agungs-MacBook-Pro:~ agungmahaputra$ mongod
2017-12-26T15:31:15.911+0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=5189 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db 64-bit host=Agungs-MacBook-Pro.local
2017-12-26T15:31:15.911+0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v3.6.0
2017-12-26T15:31:15.911+0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: a57d8e71e6998a2d0afde7edc11bd23e5661c915
2017-12-26T15:31:15.911+0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.2n  7 Dec 2017
2017-12-26T15:31:15.911+0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: system
2017-12-26T15:31:15.911+0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
2017-12-26T15:31:15.911+0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
2017-12-26T15:31:15.911+0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
2017-12-26T15:31:15.911+0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
2017-12-26T15:31:15.911+0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: {}
2017-12-26T15:31:15.911+0700 E STORAGE  [initandlisten] Failed to set up listener: SocketException: Address already in use
2017-12-26T15:31:15.911+0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] now exiting
2017-12-26T15:31:15.911+0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] shutting down with code:48
Agungs-MacBook-Pro:~ agungmahaputra$
```

Answer (score 111, accepted):

You already have a process running in the port `27017` which is used by `mongodb`. So either you need to stop the process in that port or try with different port number.

Try `mongod --port 27018`

You can change the port number of your choice.

**EDIT:**

You can also just stop all the running instances of mongo server using 
 `sudo killall mongod` as mentioned by @Dassi Orleando in the comments.
And run `mongod`

Comment: good answer, we can actually close the former mongo instance by hitting the command: `sudo killall mongod`.

Answer (score 145):

You can kill the previous **mongod** instance and start the new one.

To kill the previous mongod instance, first search for a list of tasks running on your machine by typing,

```
sudo lsof -iTCP -sTCP:LISTEN -n -P
```

Search for mongod **COMMAND** and its **PID** and type,

```
sudo kill <mongo_command_pid>
```

Now start your mongod instance by typing,

```
mongod
```

You can see MongoDB running successfully.

Comment: Probably would need to be modified to work on PC, but for mac this is perfect. Tnx

Comment: In my case, (Centos 7 Mongo 4.0.10) The service running was the actual mongo daemon and killing it just caused a different problem.
Just needed to use the 'mongo' command instead of 'mongod'

Comment: sudo killall mongod fixed the problem for me

Answer (score 11):

Summary other(`@Tony Roczz`, `@Balasubramani M`) answer to here:

## Root Cause

error: `Failed to set up listener: SocketException: Address already in use`

means:

- previously have run mongodb

  - **probably** use default port `27017`

## Solution

### (most case) kill and restart `mongod`

#### kill mongod

two method:

- use killall

  - `killall mongod`
- kill by PID

  - find mongod PID

    - method 1: `ps aux | grep mongod`
    - output can see like this: `limao 425  ... /usr/local/opt/mongodb-community/bin/mongod --config /usr/local/etc/mongod.conf`
    - method 2: `lsof -iTCP -sTCP:LISTEN -n -P`
    - output can see like this: `mongod 425 limao .. TCP 127.0.0.1:27017 (LISTEN)`
  - kill by PID: `kill -9 425`

#### re-start mongod

- most case: `mongod`
- some special case

  - `brew services start mongodb-community`

    - for install community version in Mac by: `brew install mongodb-community`

### (for some people) run with another port

- run with another port: `mongod --port 27018`

  - **only** for those want to run multiple mongod server same time

## Additional Note

### which port the running mongodb is using?

```sh
 lsof -iTCP -sTCP:LISTEN -n -P
COMMAND     PID  USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
mongod      425 limao   10u  IPv4 0xab744305e75263cf      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:27017 (LISTEN)
```

can see `27017` is current running mongodb port.

### how to check / make sure mongod is running

- check mongod status:

  - `ps aux | grep mongod`

    - output can see `mongod` service
  - `brew services list`

    - if installed by `brew` and start by `brew`

Answer (score 7):

if you're using mongodb version 4.*

in default settings, there should be a "db" folder "/data/db" having the necessary permission.

to check it the MongoDB service started

```
brew services list
```

if not then run

```
brew services start mongodb
```

run ***mongo*** instead of ***mongod***

Comment: Thanks. 
In my case, (Centos 7 Mongo 4.0.10) that's all it took.

Answer (score 6):

I solved it pasting the command below into the command line in order to close mongo's server.

```
sudo pkill -f mongod
```

"sudo" (Super User Do) runs the command admin permissions, so it will ask you for your user password

Answer (score 5):

First, shutdown the running server using:

```
mongod --shutdown
```

Then run:

```
sudo mongod
```

Answer (score 5):

After running this commands below:

```
sudo lsof -iTCP -sTCP:LISTEN -n -P
```

Search for mongod COMMAND and its PID and type,

```
sudo kill <mongo_command_pid>
```

And restarting mongod, it still fails with the same error "SocketException: Address already in use MONGODB".

Server was restarted yesterday and then this happened.

Answer (score 4):

### Just this single command

`sudo pkill -f mongod`

Comment: This is say the **same** as in the Answer by Agustín Marí. Except your answer is using bold prior to the command.

Answer (score 2):

Make Sure the error is of the port , if using macos catalina there is a reported issue for ~/data/db which also causes this.

Comment: yea I am having an issue where I am positive mongo isnt running but still getting this error

Answer (score 2):

If your mongod process is already down, just remove the .sock file in /tmp:

My mongod is already down, so does not appears in:

```
lsof -iTCP -sTCP:LISTEN -n -P
```

The error was:

```
[root@ol7db19c1 ~]# mongod -f /etc/csrs_2.conf
about to fork child process, waiting until server is ready for connections.
forked process: 6721
ERROR: child process failed, exited with error number 48
To see additional information in this output, start without the "--fork" option.
```

In the log file (/var/mongodb/db/csrs2.log):

```
2020-07-05T16:03:59.354-0300 E  STORAGE  [initandlisten] Failed to set up listener: SocketException: Address already in use
```

So, find for the socket locking:

```
ls -ltra /tmp|grep .sock
```

And just remove it (do it with caution in production environment):

```
rm -f mongodb-26002.sock
```

G-luck!

Answer (score 1):

This may sound obvious but you should check if mongodb is already running. 
So instead of first starting the the DB by running:

```
sudo mongod
```

Try directly running:

```
mongo
```