# Trying to use mongod command

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to start working with MongoDB but when I write the mongod command I get this error

2019-10-20T23:26:41.054-0500 I  CONTROL  [main] Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'

2019-10-20T23:26:41.062-0500 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=4724 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db 64-bit host=MacBook-Pro-de-Andres.local

2019-10-20T23:26:41.062-0500 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v4.2.0

2019-10-20T23:26:41.062-0500 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: a4b751dcf51dd249c5865812b390cfd1c0129c30

2019-10-20T23:26:41.062-0500 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: system

2019-10-20T23:26:41.062-0500 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: enterprise

2019-10-20T23:26:41.062-0500 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:

2019-10-20T23:26:41.062-0500 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64

2019-10-20T23:26:41.062-0500 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64

2019-10-20T23:26:41.062-0500 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: {}

2019-10-20T23:26:41.064-0500 E  STORAGE  [initandlisten] Failed to set up listener: SocketException: Address already in use

2019-10-20T23:26:41.064-0500 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] now exiting

2019-10-20T23:26:41.064-0500 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] shutting down with code:48

Comment: refer this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47975929/socketexception-address-already-in-use-mongodb

Answer (score 1):

It is a problem with your port number. Since your default port number **27017** is already allocated to mongodb, this error occurs.

In this case, You can do two things.

- you can stop the mongodb process and run mongod. Either you can run
- mongod in a different port.

  mongod --port PORT_NUMBER

port number can be **27018** or any number you wish.

Hope you can fix your issue